# What is the difference between these method type signatures (i:T):T and T=>T in Scala?

Tags: scala

In the example below,
why do these methods have a different type and how do their types differ?

```scala
Int => Int //is a shortcut for 
Function1[Int, Int].
```

But why does a method has a different type and what is the difference between `(i: Int): Int` and `Int => Int`?
Can a function have a similar type like in the first example?

```scala
scala> :t def double(i: Int): Int = i * 2
(i: Int): Int

scala> :t def double: Int => Int = i => i * 2
 Int => Int

scala> val double2 : Int => Int = i => i * 2
val double2: Int => Int = $Lambda$1197/0x00000008010c8400@54398386

scala> :t double2
Int => Int
```

Comment: This looks closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala

Comment: (Despite proposing the link, I'm hesitating to dupe-hammer the question, because some of the answers in the linked thread seem not entirely up to date)

Comment: Technically speaking the whole `(i: T): T` thing the REPL shows is just false, methods are not values as such can't have types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, `Int => Int` is just a [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `Function1[Int, Int]`.

A method has a different signature because a method in Scala is just a method in a class just like a Java method. This can have a signature like the one you mentioned: `(i: Int): Int`.

On the other hand, `Int => Int` is called a function type. The main difference is a function type is an object by itself of type `Function1[Int, Int]`. And since an object is a value, a function is also a value.

Now `val` functions are concrete instances of `Function0` through `Function22` and can be composed using `andThen`, `compose`, and `toString`. When you create it like an anonymous function (with no name), the compiler creates an anonymous `Function1` instance with an overridden `toString` method. That is why you see it differently in the REPL.